# unable to access data members of super class in sub class in same activity

Tags: java, android

I have created an activity named **ShowPairedDevices.java**  in which I have a super class named **ShowPairedDevices** to show all bluetooth paired devices.
Then I have created another class named **Demo** in the same activity which extends **ShowPairedDevices**.

```
public class ShowPairedDevices extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> pairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayAdapter<String> storePairedDevices;
BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_paired_devices);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
        pairedDevicesList.add(device.getName());
    }

    storePairedDevices = new ArrayAdapter< (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,pairedDevicesList);
    myListView.setAdapter(storePairedDevices);
}
```

}

Then I try to access ArrayList of superclass named **pairedDevicesList** in subclass , it cannot resolve it.I even tried to create object of superclass in subclass and then call members of super class through its object, but that too doesn't work. Please help.
Here's the subclass code:

```
class Demo extends ShowPairedDevices{
    pairedDevicesList.add("another device name");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Demo" class makes no sense.

You can't simply access variables like that in the class scope.
Wrap it in a function, or override a current function and access the data like that:

```
public class Demo extends ShowPairedDevices {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        pairedDevicesList.add("another device name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Moonbloom.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are placed your child class in different Package of ShowPairedDevices class.

In that case you MUST use Protected keyword for ArrayList pairedDevicesList. This is called access modifier in Java. Useful link to refer here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

At some points, you will need this implementation to reuse variables or functions.